# Sort array in c

Tags: c, qsort

I have a array of structs. lets call it `structsarray`

And i have a array of ints where the ints are index's of the stuct. Lets call it `indexarray`

I would like to sort `indexarray` but i want to compare the sorting with an `int` in `structsarray`

Any way that can be done with that setup?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comparison function such as this:

```
int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int index1 = *((const int *) a);
    int indexb = *((const int *) b);

    return structsarray[index1].field - structsarray[index2].field;
}
```

The arguments are pointer to the values in the array you are sorting. I cast the constant void pointer to a constant int pointer, and then dereference that pointer to get the actual value.

Comment: But can i somehow pass a pointer to `structsarray` as a parameter?

Comment: @Razcou If you pass the `structsarray` to `qsort` the comparison function will get two pointers to the structure instead, so you have to do e.g. `struct my_struct *struct1 = (struct my_struct *) a;`

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of qsort by implementing own comparison function. Here it is explained: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/

Answer (score 0):

Information provided is very limited.
May be you can do as follows:

Algorithm example:
bubble sort:

```
  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (index[d] > index[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {

        /* Sort index */
        swap       = index[d];
        index[d]   = index[d+1];
        index[d+1] = swap;

        /* Sort struct using above index */
        swap       = struct[d];
        struct[d]   = struct[d+1];
        struct[d+1] = swap;

      }
    }
  }
```